# existence of a infinite family of sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $S$ be a set. $T$ is a family of subsets of $S$ and $f$ is a function from $S$ to $T$. Suppose that $S_{1}\in T$, $S_{1}\neq \emptyset$ and $\exists s_{1}\in S_{1}$ such that $f(s_{1})\neq \emptyset$. Let $S_{2}=f(s_{1})$.Suppose that for every set $S_{i}$ which is obtained by this way, there exists $s_{i}\in S_{i}$ such that $f(s_{i})\neq \emptyset$.

Then, does a function F:$\mathbb{N}\rightarrow T$ such that $\forall n\in \mathbb{N}[F(n)\neq \emptyset]$  exist?

Comment: Yes. But this requires using (a weak version of) the axiom of choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, assuming the [axiom of dependent choice](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_dependent_choice). Let $S'=\{s\in S:f(s)\ne\varnothing\}$, and in the notation at the link let $$R=\{\langle s_0,s_1\rangle\in S'\times S':s_1\in f(s_0)\}\;.$$ Then $R$ is entire (i.e., $\operatorname{dom}R=S'$), so there is a sequence $\langle s_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $\langle s_k,s_{k+1}\rangle\in R$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$. But that just says that $s_{k+1}\in f(s_k)$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$, so if we let $$F=\{\langle k,f(s_k)\rangle\in\Bbb N\times T:k\in\Bbb N\}\;,$$ then $F:\Bbb N\to T$, and $F(k)=f(s_k)\ne\varnothing$ for each $k\in\Bbb N$.

The axiom of dependent choice is a weaker consequence of the full axiom of choice, which one normally assumes in most mathematical contexts anyway.